# postgres, how to reference insert ID in function to create table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to create the following Function which inserts a role into a table, gets an ID value, and then uses that ID value in a "create table" call.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION data.addtable (sch text, tbl text) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
  begin
    WITH i AS (
        SELECT nextval('data.customdata_id_seq') AS id
    )
    INSERT INTO "data"."customtables" (id,        
    ownerid,name,internalname,tableinfo)
    SELECT id, 15,tbl, 'tbl_' || id, ('{
   "counter": "2",
   "tablename": "' || sch ||'_tbl_' || id || '",
   "headers": ["ID", "First Name", "Last Name"],
   "columns": [
    {"data": "id"},
   {"data": "field_1"},
   {"data": "field_2"}
   ]
    }')::jsonb 
  FROM  i RETURNING ID;
  EXECUTE 'Create table ' || sch || '.' || 'tbl_'  || id || ' (id serial 
  primary key, field_1 varchar(100), field_2 varchar(100))';
  end;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to run this, I get the error:

```
    ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
    LINE 1: ...ELECT 'Create table ' || sch || '.' || 'tbl_'  || id || ' 
   (i...
                                                         ^
    QUERY:  SELECT 'Create table ' || sch || '.' || 'tbl_'  || id || ' (id 
    serial primary key, field_1 varchar(100), field_2 varchar(100))'
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function data.addtable(text,text) line 18 at EXECUTE
    SQL state: 42703
```

The first part of the query to insert into CustomTables works, but how do I pass/reference this ID so I can use it in the EXECUTE command to create the dynamic table? I also want it to return the ID as an integer.

UPDATE, I made some changes: Trying to figure out why this is not working?

```
   CREATE FUNCTION data.addtable (sch text, tbl text) RETURNS integer AS $$
   DECLARE
    _id data.customtables.id%TYPE;

 BEGIN  
 SELECT nextval('data.customdata_id_seq') AS id into _id;
  INSERT INTO "data"."customtables" (id, 
  ownerid,name,internalname,tableinfo)
  SELECT _id, 15,tbl, 'tbl_' || _id, ('{
 "counter": "2",
  "tablename": "' || sch ||'_tbl_' || _id || '",
  "headers": ["ID", "First Name", "Last Name"],
  "columns": [
   {"data": "id"},
     {"data": "field_1"},
     {"data": "field_2"}
    ]
  }')::jsonb;

 EXECUTE 'Create table ' || sch || '.' || 'tbl_'  || _id ' (id serial 
 primary key, field_1 varchar(100), field_2 varchar(100))';
 return _id;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For some reason, it knows _id in the top statement, but throws an error for _id as "does not exist" in the EXECUTE statement. Why?

Figured it out, was just missing a || after the _id . Working.

Comment: Why are you using a custom sequence instead of a `serial` column (or just one with a default value)? And even if not, don't use `WITH … AS` in pl/pgsql. Assign the `nextval(…)` to a simple variable.

Comment: Btw, if you are storing your own metadata about tables, I would recommend to get familiar with the [system catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) (especially [the `pg_class` table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html)) and the [many system helper functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html). Don't store the table name (only), store a reference the table entry itself as a foreign key! You don't even need to store the column names yourself, you can just get them (and much more) dynamically.

Comment: It is using a serial column, I just did renamed the table after the fact and learned that it doesn't change the sequence name dynamically. IE (original table name was Customdata, hence the customdata_id_seq.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the ID into a variable and use that in the concatenation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION data.addtable (sch text,
                               tbl text)
                RETURNS integer
AS
$$
DECLARE
  _id data.customtables.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  WITH ...
  INSERT INTO ...
         SELECT ...
         RETURNING id
                   INTO _id;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || sch || '.' || 'tbl_'  || _id || ' (id serial primary key, field_1 varchar(100), field_2 varchar(100))';
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I'm a newbie to postgres, any chance you could show what the final syntax of the function should be? I'll try to figure out, but this is all new to me. Thx for the reply.